# Rotating two UIImageViews 360 degrees

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've been trying to have two fixed sized UIImageviews with images on the them (that cover all the view), But I've been trying really hard (I give up!) to rotate each of them in a circular manner. So if I have one UIView, and the other right next to it, I would like to be able to rotate the first one (and the other inmediately, no gaps) following it, and rotating in a 360-degree fashion, it is just impossible!

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

Once of the first pieces of iPhone code I wrote was the following to display a clock, made of leaves.

A clock is created from three leaves, hours, minutes and seconds, and we have a single leaf image, which is drawn with different scaling, opacity etc., to give the appearance of a clock.

The UIView below draws a clock in the centre of the view, using translation and scaling to put the leaves in the right place. The CTM is saved and restored to save repeated translations.

You might want to look and see if it helps you with how you might deal with coordinate systems and rotating.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) 
    {
        // Initialization code
        self.minutes = 49;
        self.seconds = 0;

        // clear to transparent
        self.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self tick:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    // get time
    NSDate * time = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar * gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents * comp = [gregorian components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:time];

    // update the time
    self.seconds = [comp second];
    self.minutes = [comp minute];
    self.hours = [comp hour];

    // redisplay
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (float)toRadians:(float)deg
{
    return deg * 3.14/180.0;
}

- (void)drawClock:(CGPoint)pos hours:(NSInteger)theHours minutes:(NSInteger)theMinutes seconds:(NSInteger)theSeconds
{
    UIImage * leaf = [UIImage imageNamed:@"leaf.png"];

    // context
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // save original state
    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    // set alpha and move it to centre of clock
    CGContextSetAlpha(myContext, 0.8);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (myContext, pos.x, pos.y);

    // save centred state
    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    // rotate and translate the hour 'hand'
    CGContextRotateCTM (myContext, [self toRadians:(theHours-3.0+theMinutes/60.0)*360/12.0 - 10] );
    CGContextTranslateCTM (myContext, -5, -[leaf size].height/12);

    // draw the hour hand and restore to translated
    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, [leaf size].width/6, [leaf size].height/6), [leaf CGImage]);

    // restore centred state and resave
    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    // rotate and transform the minute 'hand'
    CGContextRotateCTM (myContext, [self toRadians:((theMinutes-15)*360.0 /60.0) - 10]);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (myContext, -5, -[leaf size].height/10);

    // draw the minute hand and restore original context
    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, [leaf size].width/5, [leaf size].height/5), [leaf CGImage]);

    // restore centred state
    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);

    // rotate and transform the second 'hand'
    CGContextSetAlpha(myContext, 0.5);
    CGContextRotateCTM (myContext, [self toRadians:((theSeconds-15)*360 /60.0) - 10]);
    CGContextTranslateCTM (myContext, -5, -[leaf size].height/10);

    // draw the second hand and restore original context
    CGContextDrawImage(myContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, [leaf size].width/5, [leaf size].height/5), [leaf CGImage]);
    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // draw clock in clock view
    [self drawClock:CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2,rect.size.height/2) hours:self.hours minutes:self.minutes seconds:self.seconds];

    // test code for centering hands
//  [self drawClock:CGPointMake(rect.size.width/2,rect.size.height/2) hours:12 minutes:00 seconds:00];
}
```